# How can I execute some small piece of PHP code in a sandbox area of my WP?

Tags: plugins, php

I'd like to execute some small piece of code like the following one:

```
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->query('SELECT DATE(post_date) AS date, COUNT(*) AS count FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' GROUP BY DATE(post_date) ORDER BY DATE(post_date)');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row->date . ': ' . $row->count . '<br>';
}
```

But I don't want to write a plugin for this small task. How can I manage it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way for execute any PHP code during development its Console from [Developer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/developer/). You can install [Developer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/developer/), and activate console module. "Debug" link will appear in top right corner in your admin bar. You can go there, and execute any php code you like.

Answer (score 4):

Context is everything with a question like this. However, since you are talking about a "sandbox" I am going to assume this is thowaway install on a development server and you just want to test bits and pieces of code without much hassle. To do that...

1. I usually drop code into a mu-plugin file-- create a directory in
   `wp-content` called `mu-plugins`. Every file in that directory will
   execute automatically.
2. Or just hack the code into the theme where ever needed. I stress the
   assumption about the "throwaway" install. This is for short term
   testing only-- for example, testing code for these question. I do
   not expect to keep it, nor deploy it. When WordPress is updated, it
   all gets overwritten. **This kind of piecemeal code testing is the only time I'd advocate hacking Core.**

Answer (score 2):

Just edit functions.php file in theme's directory which is active and write this somewhere to the end of the file:

```
function prefix_my_dump() {
    //paste your code here
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'prefix_my_dump' );
```

That hook 'wp_footer' will be echoing the content somewhere to the end of the page. You can use an other action of course. Check this page for some used actions & filters:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

Answer (score 1):

A relatively safe way to do it on even a production site is to make a new page and set it to `private` then copy the `page.php` file in your theme and change the title of that file to `page-new_page_id.php` (replace new_page_id with the id or name of the new page you created) then put your code into the content area of the new `page-new_page_id.php` file and access it as a logged in user.

Setting the new page to private will make it visible only to logged in users, so it is "relatively" safe to do even on a live site.